# Value Unknown of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

im tryin to make an app and connect it to my database(MySQL wamp) . i have made my php files and this is the NewProductActivity.java file that's giving errors.I have made a sample to do so. I have got the code from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql)

```
    package com.example.abc.androidhive;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    -private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputPrice;
    EditText inputDesc;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/create_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

        // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
        inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
  }
```

the part giving errors is:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
```

My Logcat is:

```
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Unknown of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb17d3678)
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.abc.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:100)
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.abc.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:64)
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
03-03 04:06:10.552 1944-1967/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Please suggest me of possible rectifications.

Comment: What is there in Line No 100 of NewProductActivity?

Comment: @Raghavendra extremely sorry... this code is of the NewProductActivity

Comment: @Hacketo.... no that does not help

Comment: Please post what you are getting in " Log.d("Create Response", json.toString()); "

Comment: @logan well, look more carefully the logcat ..

Comment: @logan I didn't get u. Can u tell me which is line no 100. You are getting Null pointer Excep. So

Comment: @logan Please check json is null or not after 
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product, "POST", params);

Comment: change `JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);` line to `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params));`. Hope it'll work

Comment: also check what `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product, "POST", params)` this method returns;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that what your server returns it's not a valid json. You should check what is the response of this call

I tried with casual params (name = a, price = b, description = c) and the server returns

Unknown database 'download_androidhive'

This is a string and 99% is the reason of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of this class, It is the error of your `JSONParser` class where these lines were written

```
// try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
```

I want to suggest you that it doesn't seems a single `JsonObject` at all. So just try replacing this line

```
jObj = new JSONObject(json);
```

**with**

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);  
JSONObject jObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
```